# MySQL SELECT in SELECT-clause or in WHERE-clause in order to filter further

Tags: mysql, select, union

I'm trying to filter some data, but as the data comes from 2 tables in the database I have to union them together, permitting nulls from the second table as I always need to have any values available in the first table, due to this being a product database with some products having sub-combinations and some none. Thus far I've come up with using a Union to join the two tables together, but now I need a method to filter out the data using a WHERE clause; however: this is where I get stuck. I tried putting the union as a select statement in the FROM clause: no data returned, I tried to put it into the SELECT clause as a sub: no data returned...

In short I need something like this:

```
SELECT id_product, id_product_attribute,upc1,upc2 
FROM (UNION) 
WHERE upc1='xyz' OR upc2='xyz';
```

where for example the result might be things such as:

`-> 100, null, 9912456, null`

or

`-> 200, 153, 9915559, 9977123`

Currently I have this (sorry I don't have more):

```
(SELECT     product.id_product as id_product, 
            product.upc as upc1, 
            comb.id_product_attribute, 
            comb.upc as upc2
 FROM   `db`.table1 product
   LEFT JOIN `db`.table2 comb
   ON comb.id_product = product.id_product
)
UNION
(SELECT     product.id_product as id_product, 
            product.upc as headCNK, 
            comb.id_product_attribute, 
            comb.upc
 FROM   `db`.table1 product
   RIGHT JOIN `db`.table2 comb
   ON comb.id_product = product.id_product
);
```

Also note that upc1 is coming from table 1, and upc2 from table2.

I could use the entire query, and filter out everything using some business logic in the worst case scenario, but rather not as I don't want to perform endless queries where I don't have to, my service provider doesn't like that...

**UPDATE:**
I also tried:

```
SELECT * 
from db.t1 as prod 
CROSS JOIN db.t2 as comb ON prod.id_product = comb.id_product 
WHERE prod.upc = 'xyz' OR comb.upc = 'xyz';
```

This didn't work either.

---

Placed a fiddle here with some small sample data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340d7d

The output for the '991002' used in the where clause in query *SELECT id_product, id_product_attribute, table1.upc, table2.upc* should be: *101, null, 991002, null*

And for '990001' it should then be: *101, 201, 990001, 990001*

Comment: Provide sample fiddle (or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with the data) and desired output for this data with detailed explanations.

Comment: @Akina fixed the comment; trying to see what data I can provide. But I thought the example was simple; it's basically a full join with a where clause; but I can't get it to work... Not enough practice :(

Comment: *I also tried* CROSS JOIN and ON clause? illogical. Use INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Akina Innerjoin is insufficient as I need ALL possible rows, not only rows that have a match with each other on the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all values try

```sql
SELECT t1.id_product, t2.id_product_attribute, t1.upc, t2.upc
FROM ( SELECT upc FROM table1
       UNION 
       SELECT upc FROM table2 ) t0
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 USING (upc)
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 USING (upc)
```

For definite `upc` value edit to

```
...
SELECT t1.id_product, t2.id_product_attribute, t1.upc, t2.upc
FROM ( SELECT 990001 upc ) t0
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 USING (upc)
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 USING (upc)
...
```

Comment: Did a small edit to the second query (had to make sure that I got the values for the product id from both tables as I always need this one... Building a new redirect for a website. Now it's working as I hoped! Thank you! Thanking notes and sending good vibes your way.